# sum the total of lines in an unbound field

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to modify the PO301000 to add a 'total' unbound field in the Document view which sums the OrderQty of the POLines on the grid Transaction tab.

I wanted to use a PXUnboundFormula, but the field stays at 0.

Here's what I tried :

The dac definition :

```
public abstract class usrTotalLignes : IBqlField { }
[PXDecimal]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total des lignes")]
public virtual Decimal? UsrTotalLignes { get; set; }
```

This Seems to work.

I also followed the T100 :

```
protected virtual void POLine_RowInserted(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            POLine orderLine = (POLine)e.Row;
            POOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
            POOrderExt orderExt = order.GetExtension<POOrderExt>();
            bool isLineUpdated = false;

            if (orderLine != null)
            {
                orderExt.UsrTotalLignes += orderLine.OrderQty;
                isLineUpdated = true;
            }

            if (isLineUpdated)
            {
                Base.Document.Update(order);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void POLine_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            POLine newOrderLine = (POLine)e.Row;
            POLine oldOrderLine = (POLine)e.OldRow;
            POOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
            POOrderExt orderExt = order.GetExtension<POOrderExt>();
            bool isLineUpdated = false;

            if (!sender.ObjectsEqual<POLine.orderQty>(newOrderLine, oldOrderLine))
            {
                if (oldOrderLine.OrderQty != null)
                {
                    orderExt.UsrTotalLignes -= oldOrderLine.OrderQty;
                }
                if (newOrderLine.OrderQty != null)
                {
                    orderExt.UsrTotalLignes += newOrderLine.OrderQty;
                }
                isLineUpdated = true;
            }

            if (isLineUpdated)
            {
                Base.Document.Update(order);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void POLine_RowDeleted(PXCache sender, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
        {
            POLine orderLine = (POLine)e.Row;
            POOrder order = Base.Document.Current;
            POOrderExt orderExt = order.GetExtension<POOrderExt>();
            bool isLineUpdated = false;

            if (orderLine != null)
            {
                orderExt.UsrTotalLignes -= orderLine.OrderQty;
                isLineUpdated = true;
            }

            if (isLineUpdated)
            {
                Base.Document.Update(order);
            }
        }
```

Which works when I add, edit or remove a line.

Now my problem is when I want to set the value of this unbound field at the loading of the page, here's what I tried :

```
[PXDecimal]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total des lignes")]
[PXUnboundFormula(typeof(POLine.orderQty), typeof(SumCalc<POOrderExt.usrTotalLignes>))]
public virtual void POOrder_UsrTotalLignes_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{

}
```

And I tried :

```
[PXDecimal]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Total des lignes")]
[PXUnboundFormula(typeof(Sum<POLine.orderQty>), typeof(SumCalc<POOrderExt.usrTotalLignes>))]
public virtual void POOrder_UsrTotalLignes_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{

}
```

But it still stays at 0.

I also tried to add :

```
[PXParent(typeof(Select<POOrder, Where<POOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderNbr>>, 
            And<POOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>>>>))]
```

But it just loops infintely and crashes.

Here's something else I tried (found in the t300):

```
protected void POOrder_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    POOrder order = (POOrder)e.Row;
    if (order == null) return;

    var extension = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(order);
    using (PXConnectionScope cs = new PXConnectionScope())
    {
        extension.UsrTotalLignes = 0;
        foreach(POLine line in PXSelectReadonly<POLine, 
            Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>, 
                And<POLine.orderType, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base, order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType))
        {
            extension.UsrTotalLignes += line.OrderQty;
        }
    }
}
```

Which actually works, but only if I modify a field (If i load an older record, it doesnt work until I modify it, then it writes the value), How do I ask the UI to refresh the cached value ?

Where are my errors ?

Edit:

I managed to have it work with this :

```
protected void POOrder_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            POOrder order = (POOrder)sender.Current;
            if (order == null) return;

            var extension = PXCache<POOrder>.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(order);
            using (PXConnectionScope cs = new PXConnectionScope())
            {
                extension.UsrTotalLignes = 0;
                foreach(POLine line in PXSelectReadonly<POLine, 
                    Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderNbr>>, 
                        And<POLine.orderType, Equal<Required<POOrder.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base, order.OrderNbr, order.OrderType))
                {
                    extension.UsrTotalLignes += line.OrderQty;
                }
            }
            Base.Document.Current.GetExtension<POOrderExt>().UsrTotalLignes = extension.UsrTotalLignes;
        }
```

I had to use :

```
POOrder order = (POOrder)sender.Current;
```

instead of

```
POOrder order = (POOrder)e.Row
```

else for some reason I don't get, when first loading the record it worked fine. Then when I changed any field that had a "commit" in it, it called the rowSelectingEvent again, and this time e.row was the next POOrder in the list.

Any idea why it did this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As John answer mentions, in POLine.OrderQty DAC Field there's a PXFormula attribute with a SumCalc BQL element targeting the total field which is POOrder.orderQty:

```
#region OrderQty
public abstract class orderQty : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
protected Decimal? _OrderQty;
[PXDBQuantity(typeof(POLineS.uOM), typeof(POLineS.baseOrderQty), HandleEmptyKey = true, BqlField = typeof(POLine.orderQty))]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXFormula(null, typeof(SumCalc<POOrder.orderQty>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Order Qty.", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
public virtual Decimal? OrderQty
{
    get
    {
        return this._OrderQty;
    }
    set
    {
        this._OrderQty = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

---

Sometimes you might need to implement more complex logic that isn't a good fit for a simple formula sum calculation.

You can extend POOrderEntry and call Select on the Base Transactions DataView to iterate all records shown in the Document Details tab and manually sum OrderQty of each line:

```
public class POOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<POOrderEntry>
{      
  public virtual void POOrder_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
  {
      POOrder order = e.Row as POOrder;

      if (order != null)
      {
        sender.SetValue<POOrderExt.usrTotalQuantiteCommande>(order, ComputeQuantiteCommandeTotal());
      }
  }

  public virtual void POOrder_UsrTotalQuantiteCommande_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
  {
      e.ReturnValue = ComputeQuantiteCommandeTotal();
  }

  public virtual decimal ComputeQuantiteCommandeTotal()
  {
      decimal total = 0M;

      foreach (POLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
      {
          total += (line.OrderQty != null ? line.OrderQty.Value : 0M);
      }

      return total;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the already available field "OrderQty" but which is not exposed in UI. You can directly edit .aspx file and replace DataField="OrderQty" for the new field which you are added or else you can add field from customization project as well. Have a look at below screenshots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I both hate and love you. Yet i'd like to know why my tries were unsuccessfull. I'll mark your answer as accepted if noone can help me to understand my mistakes

Comment: You can directly access the records in the Transactions tab (Document Details) DataView using the DataView Select method, I added an answer to demonstrate how.